# How to print loop results in the corresponding adjacent cells?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 columns, B and F. I'm trying to get the phonetic value for Range("B:B") into Range("F:F"). It shows to be testing every cell in B, but the results are not showing into the corresponding cell.

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set rng = Range("B:B")
i = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2))

    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = rng.Phonetic.Text
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I also plan to test if column F is empty or not, if not empty then get phonetic. As shown below.

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set rng = Range("B:B")
i = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2))
    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
        If Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = rng.Phonetic.Text
        End If
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I am not familar so much with the `Phonetic` Class, but if you don't advance `rng` inside the loop, won't you get the same result? don't you need to `Cells(i, "F").Value = Cells(i, "B").Phonetic.Text` ?

Comment: How do you know what the Activecell is? If you want to loop through cells use Cells(i,j) for the locations explicitly. Nothing in your current code alters the ActiveCell so your loop won't do much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after trial and error. I figured it out (probably there is a better way).

```
Sub test()

'Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

'Set rng = Range("B:B")
i = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2))

    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
        If Cells(i, 6).Value = "" Then
        Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, 4).Value = Cells(i, 2).Phonetic.Text
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: see my answer for a more efficient solution. I edited right now after getting from this code what you intended `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)` to be

Answer (score 1):

**edited** after OP's clarification about what `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)` was intended to be

to loop through non blank cells of a range you can use [`Specialcells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of `Range` object

the following example loops through column "B" cells with *constant* value  (i.e. that doesn't derive from a formula):

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Offset(0, 6).Text = "" Then cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = cell.Phonetic.Text '<--| get cells with 'constant' values
Next cell
```

if you want to narrow the filtering down to *constant* text values cells then add `xlTextvalues` parameter:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| get cells with 'constant' text values
    If cell.Offset(0, 6).Text = "" Then cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = cell.Phonetic.Text
Next cell
```

should your cells be filled with formulas then you want to use `xlCellTypeFormulas` as first parameter, always with possible `xlTextValues` second one